# How to test for IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults

Tags: c#, wcf, attributes, servicebehavior

I can check if the behavior is set or not with:

```
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MyService), typeof(ServiceBehavior))
```

How do I check if a specific property is defined and set within the ServiceBehavior attribute? for example the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was simple, I needed to cast the attribute and then check for the property:

```
Attribute behavior = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(myService.GetType(), typeof(ServiceBehaviorAttribute));
if (behavior != null)
{
    if (!((ServiceBehaviorAttribute)behavior).IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults)
    {
        throw new Exception(); // or whatever
    }
}
```

The service would be something like:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyService
{ }
```

Hope this helps someone.